# Using Python's multiprocessing.shared_memory for dict

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

The Python docs have an example for sharing a numpy array. https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an example online for sharing a dict acrosss processes. Can anyone show how to do that?

Comment: A dict is not prepared to share its data in shared memory. This doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelButscher can you list the python data structures that can be used in shared memory? and maybe the reason or a link to it for why a dict cant be in shared memory

Comment: By "multiprocessing.shared_memory.ShareableList" simple types like "int, float, bool, str (less than 10M bytes each), bytes (less than 10M bytes each), and None" can be used. Apart from that only types where you can specify the memory location of their data can be used. These are ctypes types and some from external libraries like numpy but usual Python standard types don't support it.